# Evaluate $ \int \frac{3+4x}{x+x^2y}dx $.

Tags: integration

> $$
> \int \frac{3+4x}{x+x^2y}dx
> $$

The constant $y$ is basically confusing me a lot. How do I tackle questions with constants like this?

Comment: Would you be able to do the integration if, instead of $y$, it was a number like 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shall assume that $y\neq0$. Note that 
$$
\int\frac{3+4x}{x+x^2y}\,dx=\int\frac{3+4x}{x(1+yx)}\,dx
=\int\left(\frac{3}{x}-\frac{3y-4}{xy+1}\right)\,dx
$$
Therefore
ִִִִ$$
\int\frac{3+4x}{x+x^2y}\,dx=3\ln|x|-\frac{3y-4}{y}\ln|xy+1|+C
$$